# Tengo que crear una variable auxiliar en donde tenga los siguientes campos "código y número de hoja, comprobante, articulo y combo"

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo que crear una variable auxiliar en donde tenga los siguientes campos "código y número de hoja, comprobante, articulo y combo"

```
----Cursor----

Declare cursordev Cursor
For Select Cast(ec.fecha_fin_entrega As NVarchar(20)) As fecha_registro
         , Cast(ec.id_repartidor As VarChar(20)) As id_repartidor
         , Cast(ef.id_opcion_entrega As NVarchar(10)) As tipo_registro
         , Cast(ec.id_hoja_reparto As NVarchar(5)) As codigo_hoja_reparto
         , Cast(ec.numero_hoja_reparto As Numeric(18)) As numero_hoja_reparto
         , Cast(ec.id_repartidor As NVarchar(10)) As codigo_transportista
         , Cast(fec.tipo_documento As NVarchar(50)) As codigo_comprobante
         , Cast(fec.sucursal As SmallInt) As sucursal_comprobante
         , Cast(fec.numero_documento As Numeric(18)) As numero_comprobante
         , Cast(ei.codigo_articulo As NVarchar(24)) As codigo_producto
         , Cast(ei.cantidad_a_entregar As Numeric(18, 2)) As cantidad_facturada
         , Cast(pdahr.om_unidad_venta As NVarchar(10)) As um_vta
         , Cast(Case
                    When pdahr.om_tipo_comprobante = 'O' Then ei.cantidad_entregada
                Else ei.cantidad_a_entregar - ei.cantidad_entregada
                End As Numeric(18, 2)) As om_cantidad_devolucion
         , Cast(ef.id_motivo_no_entrega As VarChar(20)) As id_motivo_no_entrega
         , Cast(ef.observaciones As NVarchar(512)) As observaciones
         , Cast(Case
                    When pdahr.om_tipo_comprobante = 'O' Then Case
                                                                  When ef.id_opcion_entrega = 1 Then 'T'
                                                              Else 'P'
                                                              End
                Else Case
                         When ef.id_opcion_entrega = 3 Then 'T'
                     Else 'P'
                     End
                End As VarChar(1)) As tipo_devolucion
         , Cast(ef.reasignar As VarChar(1)) As reasignar
         , Cast(GetDate() As NVarchar(20)) As fechahora_ultimamodificacion
         , Cast(pdahr.om_numero_linea As Int)
         , Cast(pdahr.om_tipo_comprobante As VarChar(1))
         , Cast(pdahr.om_cantidad_pedida As Int) As cantidad_pedida
         , Cast(pdahr.om_codigo_combo As NVarchar(24)) As codigo_combo
           From e_entregas_cabecera As ec
                Left Join e_entregas_facturas As ef On ec.id_entrega = ef.id_entrega
                Left Join i_facturas_entrega_cabecera As fec On ef.id_factura = fec.id_factura 
                            And ec.id_hoja_reparto = fec.id_hoja_reparto 
                            And ec.numero_hoja_reparto = fec.numero_hoja_reparto
                Left Join e_entregas_items As ei On ef.id_entrega = ei.id_entrega 
                            And ef.id_factura = ei.id_factura
                Left Join i_articulos As a On ei.codigo_articulo = a.codigo_articulo
                Left Join arcor_pda.dbo.om_hoja_reparto As pdahr On pdahr.om_hoja_reparto = fec.id_hoja_reparto 
                            And pdahr.om_numero_hoja_reparto = fec.numero_hoja_reparto 
                            And pdahr.om_codigo_factura = fec.tipo_documento 
                            And pdahr.om_sucursal = fec.sucursal 
                            And pdahr.om_numero_factura = fec.numero_documento 
                            And pdahr.om_codigo_articulo = ei.codigo_articulo 
                            And pdahr.om_numero_linea = ei.numero_linea
           Where ec.exportado = '0' 
                And (ei.cantidad_entregada < ei.cantidad_a_entregar Or pdahr.om_tipo_comprobante = 'O') 
                And pdahr.om_codigo_combo Is Not Null 
                And pdahr.om_codigo_combo <> '' 
                And pdahr.om_codigo_articulo <> pdahr.om_codigo_combo
           Group By ec.fecha_fin_entrega
                  , ec.id_repartidor
                  , ef.id_opcion_entrega
                  , ec.id_hoja_reparto
                  , ec.numero_hoja_reparto
                  , fec.tipo_documento
                  , fec.sucursal
                  , fec.numero_documento
                  , ei.codigo_articulo
                  , ei.cantidad_a_entregar
                  , pdahr.om_unidad_venta
                  , pdahr.om_tipo_comprobante
                  , ei.cantidad_entregada
                  , ef.id_motivo_no_entrega
                  , ef.observaciones
                  , ef.reasignar
                  , pdahr.om_numero_linea
                  , pdahr.om_tipo_comprobante
                  , pdahr.om_cantidad_pedida
                  , pdahr.om_codigo_combo;

---Abrimos el Cursor---

Open cursordev;

Fetch Next From cursordev Into @Fecha_Registro
                             , @Id_Repartidor
                             , @Tipo_Registro
                             , @Codigo_Hoja_Reparto
                             , @Numero_Hoja_Reparto
                             , @Codigo_Transportista
                             , @Codigo_Comprobante
                             , @Sucursal_Comprobante
                             , @Numero_Comprobante
                             , @Codigo_Producto
                             , @Cantidad_Facturada
                             , @Um_Vta
                             , @Cantidad_Devolucion
                             , @Id_Motivo_No_Entrega
                             , @Observaciones
                             , @Tipo_Devolucion --@OM_CANTIDAD_PEDIDA,
                             , @Reasignacion
                             , @Fechahora_Ultimamodificacion
                             , @Numero_Linea
                             , @Tipo_Comprobante
                             , @Exportado
                             , @Om_Codigo_Combo;

While @@Fetch_Status = 0
Begin
    Print ' Fecha de Registro ' + @Fecha_Registro + ' id de Repartidor ' + @Id_Repartidor;

    --' Exportado ' +@EXPORTADO 
    --' Codigo Combo '+ @OM_CODIGO_COMBO 

    Fetch Next From cursordev Into @Fecha_Registro
                                 , @Id_Repartidor
                                 , @Tipo_Registro
                                 , @Codigo_Hoja_Reparto
                                 , @Numero_Hoja_Reparto
                                 , @Codigo_Transportista
                                 , @Codigo_Comprobante
                                 , @Sucursal_Comprobante
                                 , @Numero_Comprobante
                                 , @Codigo_Producto
                                 , @Cantidad_Facturada
                                 , @Um_Vta
                                 , @Cantidad_Devolucion
                                 , @Id_Motivo_No_Entrega
                                 , @Observaciones
                                 , @Tipo_Devolucion
                                 , @Reasignacion
                                 , @Fechahora_Ultimamodificacion
                                 , @Numero_Linea
                                 , @Tipo_Comprobante
                                 , @Exportado --@OM_CANTIDAD_PEDIDA,
                                 , @Om_Codigo_Combo;
End;

--Cerramos el Cursor---

Close cursordev;

Deallocate cursordev;
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. No se entiende, cuál es el objetivo de la pregunta. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: Hola como  te va? Deje el cursor que creado y ahora necesito armar un variable auxiliar con los campos "código y número de hoja, comprobante, articulo y combo" pero no se como hacerlo. En si la pregunta es como se puede armar una variable auxiliar con la combinación de estos campos "código y número de hoja, comprobante, articulo y combo".

Comment: Me parece que estás pidiendo algo para hacer cosas que no corresponden a SQL Server. Si el cursor solo va a mostrar esos datos en pantalla, hay mejores formas de hacerlo.